# SQL Server 2016, Web Edition replication options

Tags: sql-server-2016, database-replication

I am working with Web Edition SQL Server 2016 and need to create a read/only replica.

I do not believe there is anyway of doing this. I think Standard Edition is needed at minimum.

Am I correct?